# Alcatel One Touch pop C3: How to install TWRP?

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, flashtool

The problem I'm having is mainly because all the websites that I've searched are next to impossible to follow. Either links are dead, or something horribly went wrong while translating, so I'm asking here.

I got an Alcatel One Touch pop C3. Not the "one touch 3" version, the 'C' is significant. Up until recently, it was impossible to load a different ROM on it, but it seems Lineage OS has released a version for the One Touch pop C3, so I wanted to give it a try.

with `adb` I was able to check that the bootloader is unlocked, with `fastboot` I tried to upload the TWRP image (`TWRP-3.1.0.0-PopC3.img`), but it won't work.

I can boot into fastboot with:
`adb reboot bootloader` the device boots into a blank screen with `=> FASTBOOT mode...`

I can list the device in question with `fastboot devices`

When I then do `fastboot flashing unlock` nothing happens, it just sits there.

Same thing happens when I do `fastboot oem unlock`.

When I tried to do `fastboot flash recovery TWRP-3.1.0-0.PopC3.img`, I get the following error: `FAILED (remote: 'partition 'recovery' not support flash')` *(sic)*.

I was lead to believe, that the only way to successfully upload the file onto the phone, is via "SP Flash Tool" I have version v5.1824.00 installed which I believe is the latest one.

And that's where I'm pretty much stuck. I've installed the MT65xx USB VCOM drivers in a Windows VM, and that's pretty much it at this point.

I've also tried the Linux version of SP Flash Tool, but whenever I select the scatter loading file, and choose the TRWP image as recovery image, it just sits there and doesn't seem to do anything.

Do I need to boot into the fastboot bootloader, or something?

I can access the phone with `adb` and `fastboot` just fine, but I have no idea what that `SP Flash Tool` is doing, or if it is doing anything at all.

Comment: More detailed explanation of the process you tried and any messages from the failed process would improve your chances of getting an answer. As far as and and fastboot is. Concerned. `How did you find out that your bootloader is unlocked with adb?` `Specifically what and command did you use?` `Where you in the bootloader when attempting to use fastboot?` `What fastboot command did you use to try to flash the recovery .img?` `What was the error message after the failed flash attempt?`

Comment: @BoLawson alright, I amended my question. Pretty much all websites I found, claimed that MediaTek devices are generally unlocked, but I need to use that SP Flash Tool utility. Most of what I used just doesn't report anything. No error messages, etc.

Comment: Umm, I hate to break it to you but your bootloader is not unlocked. What adb command did you use that stated your bootloader was unlocked? I am interested to learn a new command.

Comment: @BoLawson Well, what I found online, led me to believe that since there are no error messages, it is unlocked. In fact most sources stated that most MediaTek cellphones aren't locked right from the get go. By now I managed to load roms with SP Flash Tool, but it ain't working. After a factory reset, it only ever goes back to the recovery menu and cannot boot into regular Android.

Comment: Here are some other resources to learn about android along with android enthusiast.
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/fastboot/
https://www.xda-developers.com

Comment: Well, it seems as if I can't really access the phone right now anyway. It won't boot into anything except the recovery boot loader. I guess I've bricked it.

Comment: Hi! Mediatek phones don't support flashing through fastboot, as far as my experience tell me. Now, for SP Flash Tool, did you try [Step 10](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool) exactly when it needed to be tried?

Comment: @Firelord yep, did exactly as stated there, and even got the "green ring" as they call it. Still, only boots into recovery shows "Erasing" for a split second and then shows me the recovery boot menu. Not sure what to do from here on out.